# Error al conectar a MySQL con CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Intento conectarme a MySQL pero me sale el siguiente error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()
>
> Filename: >C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 135
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Como puedo corregir ese error? le agradecería mucho

Comment: Que version de php estas usando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los que tienes que usar es la librería mysqli, en el database.php.

el dbdriver debe de que así

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto el controlador mysql ya está obsoleto